# Find the complex integral over a path

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have to integrate the complex function $$z+1/z$$ which is parameterized by $\gamma(t), 0 \le t\le 1$ and satisfies $Im\gamma(t) > 0$, $\gamma(0) = -4+i$ and $\gamma(1) = 6+2i$.

Can I assume the path between $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$ is a line then find the line equation $\gamma(t)$?

Comment: Yes that is fine. You could have a different path meeting the conditions, which will give a different result in general. I can't see why the question setter has not said to simply use the straight line path.

Comment: I found the line equation as $\gamma(t) = 10t-4+i(t+1)$ but I can't figure out  how to integrate z + 1/z with this parameter using $\int_{gamma} f(z)dz&=\int_gamma f(z(t))z'(t)dt $ Does it have anything to do with principal branch of log?